# shareProcessNamespace not working in k8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes

### problem description:

```
❯ kubectl version --short
Flag --short has been deprecated, and will be removed in the future. The --short output will become the default.
Client Version: v1.24.2
Kustomize Version: v4.5.4
Server Version: v1.23.4
```

The cri is docker

```
docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.17
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.17.11
 Git commit:        100c701
 Built:             Mon Jun  6 23:02:57 2022
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.17
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.17.11
  Git commit:       a89b842
  Built:            Mon Jun  6 23:01:03 2022
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.6
  GitCommit:        10c12954828e7c7c9b6e0ea9b0c02b01407d3ae1
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.2
  GitCommit:        v1.1.2-0-ga916309
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

I tried to use temporal pod to debug coredns pod with below commands but failed

```
❯ kubectl debug -it ephemeral-demo --image=busybox:1.28 --target=coredns-64897985d-2xgd6
Targeting container "coredns-64897985d-2xgd6". If you don't see processes from this container it may be because the container runtime doesn't support this feature.
Error from server (NotFound): pods "ephemeral-demo" not found
```

#### ps

I found the feature of podShareProcessNamespace is enabled by default after 1.17
And I can also finish the job described in the https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-application/debug-running-pod/#ephemeral-container with below details

```
❯ kubectl debug -it ephemeral-demo --image=busybox:1.28 --target=ephemeral-demo

Targeting container "ephemeral-demo". If you don't see processes from this container it may be because the container runtime doesn't support this feature.
Defaulting debug container name to debugger-mqth2.
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
/ #
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the feature is functional. It is misunderstand the meaning of the doc https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-application/debug-running-pod/#ephemeral-container.

We can use below two steps to use the feature of using ephemeral container to debug.

1. patch your deployment with below command

```
kubectl patch deployment coredns --patch '
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      shareProcessNamespace: true'
```

2. start a ephemeral container to use debug tools to debug

```
kubectl debug -it -c debug coredns-7f96c4ccc7-pfhxj --image busybox:latest
```

---

But the error promotion(If you don't see processes from this container it may be because the container runtime doesn't support this feature.) is some kind of confusing.

And the description that The --target parameter targets the process namespace of another container in the doc https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-application/debug-running-pod/#ephemeral-container can also be a little confusing.

---

By reading this i may know what the vaule that --target can be assigned which can be the name of the container in the pod spec.